# Small integers with small modular inverse

Tags: number-theory, inequality, modular-arithmetic

Let $a,n$ be relatively prime positive integers with $a<n$, and let $b$ be the unique integer with $0<b<n$ and $ab=1$ mod $n$. Can we find all such pairs $(n,a)$ so that both $a,b$ are small? For example can we find all $(n,a)$ such that $$ \frac{a+b}{n}<\frac{1}{30}?$$

I can't find any constraints on $n$ or $a$ for this inequality. (Of course this holds trivially if $a=1$ and $n>60$, so I want to exclude this case.)

Comment: If $n+1=s^2$ then $s$ is its own inverse and $\frac{s+s}{n} \approx \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$. This means there are solutions for arbitrarily large $n$, so you're not going to be able to find an upper bound. I'm pretty sure there will be increasingly many for large $n$, in fact.

Comment: If $1<a,b<\sqrt n$, then $ab$ can never be $\equiv 1\pmod n$. So you’ll need $n>3600$ or so.

Comment: There are infinitely many $(n, a)$'s satisfying your condition. What exactly do you want?

Comment: @ZoeAllen Or can we show that for such $n$ and $a$, we must have $ab=n+1$?

Comment: @PinkRabbit I was wondering that if they can be classified, even there are infinitely many of them

Comment: $ab=2n+1,3n+1, \dots$ are all also possible, and have infinitely many solutions. For any $r$ you can find arbitarily large solutions to $rn+1 = s^2$. Take $s=rt+1$ and you'll find $r|(rt+1)^2$ so this always gives an integer solution for $n$. As $t$ gets larger, we find $r^2 t^2 \approx rn$ so $$\frac{a+b}{n} = \frac{rt+1+rt+1}{n} \approx 2\sqrt{\frac{r}{n}}$$
meaning the solutions are always small for large $n$.